# How do you translate chart coordinates to device pixels in SkiaSharp?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm attempting to write a matrix transform to convert chart points to device pixels in SkiaSharp.  I have it functional as long as I use 0,0 as my minimum chart coordinates but if I need to to step up from a negative number, it causes the drawing to shift left and down.  That is to say that the X Axis is shifted to the left off the window and the Y Axis is shift down off the window.

This is intended to be a typical line chart (minimum chart point at the lower left while minimum device point at the upper left).  I have accounted for that already in the transform.

While stepping through code I can see that the coordinates returned from the Matrix are not what I expect them to be, so I believe the issue to be with my transform but I haven't been able to pinpoint it.

**UPDATE:**  After further examination, I believe I was mistaken, it is not shifted, it's just not scaling properly to the max end of the screen.  There is a bigger margin at the top and right side of the chart than there should be, but the bottom and left side are fine.  I've been undable to determine why the scaling doesn't fill the canvas.

Below are my matrix methods:

```cs
private SKMatrix ChartToDeviceMatrix, DeviceToChartMatrix;
private void ConfigureTransforms(SKPoint ChartMin, 
    SKPoint ChartMax, SKPoint DeviceMin, SKPoint DeviceMax)
{
    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
    float xScale = (DeviceMax.X - DeviceMin.X) / (ChartMax.X - ChartMin.X);
    float yScale = (DeviceMin.Y - DeviceMax.Y) / (ChartMax.Y - ChartMin.Y);

    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.SetScaleTranslate(xScale, yScale, DeviceMin.X, DeviceMax.Y);
    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.TryInvert(out this.DeviceToChartMatrix);
}

// Transform a point from chart to device coordinates.
private SKPoint ChartToDevice(SKPoint point)
{
    return this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.MapPoint(point);
}
```

The code invoking this is:

```cs
void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
    SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    float strokeWidth = 1;
    float margin = 10;

    // SKPaint definitions omitted for brevity.

    var ChartMin = new SKPoint(-10, -1); // Works fine if I change this to 0,0
    var ChartMax = new SKPoint(110, 11);
    var DeviceMin = new SKPoint(margin, margin);
    var DeviceMax = new SKPoint(info.Width - margin, info.Height - margin);
    const float stepX = 10;
    const float stepY = 1;
    const float tickX = 0.5;
    const float tickY = 0.075F;

    // Prepare the transformation matrices.
    this.ConfigureTransforms(ChartMin, ChartMax, DeviceMin, DeviceMax);

    // Draw the X axis.
    var lineStart = new SKPoint(ChartMin.X, 0);
    var lineEnd = new SKPoint(ChartMax.X, 0);
    canvas.DrawLine(this.ChartToDevice(lineStart), this.ChartToDevice(lineEnd), axisPaint);

    // X Axis Tick Marks
    for (float x = stepX; x <= ChartMax.X - stepX; x += stepX)
    {
        var tickMin = new SKPoint(x, -tickY);
        var tickMax = new SKPoint(x, tickY);
        canvas.DrawLine(this.ChartToDevice(tickMin), this.ChartToDevice(tickMax), axisPaint);
    }

    // Draw the Y axis.
    // The inversion of above, basically the same.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to discover my own problem with enough time.  I wasn't calculating the offset correct.
`this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.SetScaleTranslate(xScale, yScale, DeviceMin.X, DeviceMax.X);`

Should have been:

`this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.SetScaleTranslate(xScale, yScale, -ChartMin.X * xScale + DeviceMin.Y, -ChartMin.Y * yScale + DeviceMax.Y);`

Final Matrix method was:

```cs
private SKMatrix ChartToDeviceMatrix, DeviceToChartMatrix;
private void ConfigureTransforms(SKPoint ChartMin, SKPoint ChartMax, SKPoint DeviceMin, SKPoint DeviceMax)
{
    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
    float xScale = (DeviceMax.X - DeviceMin.X) / (ChartMax.X - ChartMin.X);
    float yScale = (DeviceMin.Y - DeviceMax.Y) / (ChartMax.Y - ChartMin.Y);
    float xOffset = -ChartMin.X * xScale + DeviceMin.X;
    float yOffset = -ChartMin.Y * yScale + DeviceMax.Y;

    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.SetScaleTranslate(xScale, yScale, xOffset, yOffset);
    this.ChartToDeviceMatrix.TryInvert(out this.DeviceToChartMatrix);
}
```